# Cal Web API with headers authorization

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I request web api from html view with header authorization 
But unfortunately when i put this section headers

```
{authorization:'basic fdgxvgxsa='}
```

in my ajax request it is not make any request

My ajax call is as following

```
$.ajax{
Url:http/localhost:1234/api/isuserauthinticated
Headers:{'authorization..... '}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use **beforeSend** function to set you autherization headers in .

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  beforeSend: function(request) {
    request.setRequestHeader("authorization", authorizationToken);
  }
});
```

Comment: thanks a lot , but i need to tell you that also i enable CORS in the beginning of class not in the action itself and that solve my issue